# How to prevent rewriting shiny blocks by adding outputs to functions?

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app essentially generates several headers and plots based on the chosen `selectInput`. However, since the the code is very repetitive I have managed to use functions to simplify the major components of each plot to 4 functions. I want to take this a step further and call each of those four functions from a single function.

The four functions that I have simplified to and the code that generates the output are:

```
panel1Data <- reactive({
  panelData(1)
})

output$panel1header <- renderUI({
  panelHeader(1)
})

output$panel1definition <- renderUI({
  panelDefinition(1)
})

output$panel1plot <- renderPlot({
  panelPlot(panel1Data(), 1)  
})
```

My attempt to reduce this further to a single line is as follows:

```
panel1Data <- reactive({
    panelData(1)
})

panels <- function(data, header, definition, plot, number){

header <- renderUI({
  panelHeader(number)
})

output$definition <- renderUI({
  panelDefinition(number)
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
  panelPlot(data, number)  
}) 
}    

panels(panel1Data(), output$panel1header, output$panel1definition, output$panel1plot, 1)
```

However, this doesn't generate output. I'm guessing this is because functions aren't just simple text replacements but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can try to pack all the dynamically generated components into a function, then call this function within `renderUI`.  Please see below toy example:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  panel1Data <- reactive({
    panelData(1)
  })

  createPanel <- function(id) {
    headerID <- paste0("header_", id)
    defID <- paste0("def_", id)
    plotID <- paste0("plot_", id)

    res <- list(
      h1(headerID), br(),
      h3(defID), br(),
      h3(paste0(plotID), " goes here.")
    )
    return(res)  
  }
  output$UI <- renderUI({
    createPanel(input$selection)
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(

  h3("Using renderUI and uiOutput"),
  selectInput("selection", label="", choices=c("a", "b", "c")),
  uiOutput("UI")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is a very good post showing common Shiny tricks: [Create re-useable UI elements](http://zevross.com/blog/2016/04/19/r-powered-web-applications-with-shiny-a-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet-with-40-example-apps/)